# Stop service when device is locked and start it when it's not

Tags: android

I'm a new one in android development.I wanna know how can start service if device is unlocked and stop it when it's not. I've found information about using `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` it works fine but it needs that device was locked and then unlocked before my service could be started.

Comment: you can do it on screen on and off..for that use broadcast receiver of type `USER_PRESENT`

Comment: Maybe you will find something useful in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522905/how-to-stop-service-when-action-screen-off)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for [ACTION_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) and [ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF).

Notice you'll have to call [registerReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) to listen for these intents.  Just registering them in AndroidManifest.xml will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare actions in `Manifest` file for `BroadcastReceiver`, then it'll work only when you register broadcast receiver. And when your application is closed, it'll not work. So register receiver in service.

For that create a service to register a receiver

```
public class UnlockService extends Service {
```

and register `SCREEN_ON` AND `SCREEN_OFF` `BroadcastReceiver` `onCreate` of that service

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenUnlockReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}
```

and register the service in any activity from which you have to start detecting events.

```
Intent service = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, UnlockService.class);
startService(service);
```

It'll register `BroadcastReceiver` for checking `SCREEN_ON` and `SCREEN_OFF` events.

Then declare `ScreenUnlockReceiver`

```
public class ScreenUnlockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

and write in `onReceive` method

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(action)) {
        // start the service
    } else if(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equals(action)) {
        // stop the service
    }
}
```

and done.

Comment: But when user unlocks device(press power button) he sees lock screen. (Here will work action_screen_on) So, in the end we got working service and locked phone.

Comment: Use device admin to check login success or failed.

Comment: These receivers will be unregistered by the system after some time if registered this way.